# Having problems while inserting values into a max binary heap

Tags: c, realloc, binary-heap

I created a binary heap using C. Here are the functions to initialize the heap and insert the values

```
int *heapArray; // pointer to array of elements in heap
int capacity = 0; // maximum possible size of min heap, initially set to 0
int heap_size; // Current number of elements in min heap
int d = 2;  //max number of children per node

int getParent(int i) //get the parent index of i
{
    return (i/d);
}

bool isFull() //check if heap is full
{
    if(heap_size == capacity)
        return true;
    if(heap_size < capacity)
        return false;
}

void initializeHeap(int cap) //initialize the heap
{
    heap_size = 0;
    capacity = cap;
    heapArray = (int*)malloc(cap*sizeof(int));
}

void insertValue(int x) //insert a value into the heap
{
    if(isFull()) //If heap is already full, double the heap size
    {
        capacity = 2*capacity;
        heapArray = realloc(heapArray,capacity*sizeof(int));
    }

    heap_size = heap_size + 1;
    heapArray[heap_size] = x; //insert new value into heap (not zero-indexed)
    maxHeapSwim(heap_size);
}

void maxHeapSwim(int k) //move value up the heap to maintain max-heap order
{
    while(k > 1 && heapArray[getParent(k)] < heapArray[k])
    {
        swap(&heapArray[k],&heapArray[parent(k)]);
        k = parent(k);
    }
}
```

Then in the main() method, I tried to insert values into the heap and print out the values:

```
int main()
{

  initializeHeap(1); //Set the heap capacity to 1

  insertValue(2);
  insertValue(3);
  insertValue(1);
  insertValue(6);
  insertValue(4);

  printf("\n");
  printf("%i", heapArray[1]);
  printf("\n");
  printf("%i", heapArray[2]);
  printf("\n");
  printf("%i", heapArray[3]);
  printf("\n");
  printf("%i", heapArray[4]);
  printf("\n");
  printf("%i", heapArray[5]);
  printf("\n");

  return 0;

}
```

Since this is a max-heap, I was hoping the output would look like this:

```
6
4
1
2
3
```

But instead, it looked like this:

```
6
4
1
0
3
```

I don't understand. Why is the 2 turning into a 0? I have a feeling it has something to do with how I'm doubling the heap size in the *insertValue()* function....maybe the way I'm using realloc. Is there something I'm doing incorrectly?

Another thing to note is that my binary heap isn't zero-indexed. The first value is inserted into heapArray[1], the second value into heapArray[2], and so on.

Comment: Don't ignore warnings.

Comment: An array of n elements goes from 0 to n-1.

Comment: @stark I'm aware of that. But I've seen many examples where a binary heap is built by keeping the 0th index of the array empty and the first value is placed at index 1. That's what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: Then you need to allocate n+1 spaces in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Some changes on first section of your code works for me.

Implement `swap()` and some minor changes.

***Code***

```
#define false 0
#define true 1

int *heapArray; // pointer to array of elements in heap
int capacity = 0; // maximum possible size of min heap, initially set to 0
int heap_size; // Current number of elements in min heap
int d = 2;  //max number of children per node

int getParent(int i) //get the parent index of i
{
    return (i/d);
}

void maxHeapSwim(int k) //move value up the heap to maintain max-heap order
{
    while(k > 1 && heapArray[getParent(k)] < heapArray[k])
    {
        //swap(&heapArray[k],&heapArray[parent(k)]);
        int x=heapArray[k];
        heapArray[k]=heapArray[getParent(k)];
        heapArray[getParent(k)]=x;
        k = getParent(k);
    }
}

int  isFull() //check if heap is full
{
    if(heap_size == capacity)
        return true;
    if(heap_size < capacity)
        return false;
}

void initializeHeap(int cap) //initialize the heap
{
    heap_size = 0;
    capacity = cap;
    heapArray = (int*)malloc(cap*sizeof(int));
}

void insertValue(int x) //insert a value into the heap
{
    if(isFull()) //If heap is already full, double the heap size
    {
        capacity = 2*capacity;
        heapArray = realloc(heapArray,capacity*sizeof(int));
    }

    heap_size = heap_size + 1;
    heapArray[heap_size] = x; //insert new value into heap (not zero-indexed)
    maxHeapSwim(heap_size);
}




int main()
{  

  initializeHeap(1); //Set the heap capacity to 1

  insertValue(2);
  insertValue(3);
  insertValue(1);
  insertValue(6);
  insertValue(4);

  printf("\n");
  printf("%i", heapArray[1]);
  printf("\n");
  printf("%i", heapArray[2]);
  printf("\n");
  printf("%i", heapArray[3]);
  printf("\n");
  printf("%i", heapArray[4]);
  printf("\n");
  printf("%i", heapArray[5]);
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

> output

```
./code 


6
4
1
2
3
```

Comment: It didn't work. I'm still getting the output 6,4,1,0,3 instead of 6,4,1,2,3

Comment: Still not working. The only things you changed in my code is the maxHeapSwim function and `define false 0` and `define true 1`. Are there any other changes that I'm missing?

Comment: Yes thats true i only change`maxHeapSwim()` but as i show in output its works on my terminal.

Comment: this is output of code on online compiler: https://www.jdoodle.com/a/SPC

Comment: Yeah but it still didn't work. I managed to solve the problem though. I'll post it as an answer later.

Comment: As i show in online compiler your code is work correctly

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
void insertValue(int x)
{
    if(capacity < 10)
    {
        capacity = 10;
        heapArray = (int*)realloc(heapArray,capacity*sizeof(int));
    }
    if(heap_size >= capacity/2)
    {
        capacity += 10;
        heapArray = (int*)realloc(heapArray,capacity*sizeof(int));
    }

    heap_size = heap_size + 1;
    heapArray[heap_size] = x;
    maxHeapSwim(heap_size);
}
```

The key is to make sure the binary heap is never full.